# framework not found GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've an iOS application that has been up on the App Store for about 6 months now and everything worked fine. But when I updated my Xcode to 11.1 I'm getting errors.

I'm getting this kind of error

> framework not found GoogleMobileAds

And here is the error message I'm getting in Xcode.

> Ld /Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.app/MyDogwalk normal arm64 (in target 'MyDogwalk' from project 'MyDogwalk')
>       cd /Users/puttemac/Desktop/MyDogwalk-ios/MyDogwalk
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios11.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.1.sdk -L/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseDatabase -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseInstanceID -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseStorage -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Kingfisher -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gRPC-C++ -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gRPC-Core -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/leveldb-library -F/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/puttemac/Desktop/MyDogwalk-ios/MyDogwalk/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/puttemac/Desktop/MyDogwalk-ios/MyDogwalk/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current -F/Users/puttemac/Desktop/MyDogwalk-ios/MyDogwalk/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -filelist /Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyDogwalk.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyDogwalk.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyDogwalk.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyDogwalk_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyDogwalk.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyDogwalk.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework FirebaseFirestore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseStorage -framework Foundation -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleDataTransport -framework GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework GoogleUtilities -framework Kingfisher -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework grpc -framework grpcpp -framework leveldb -framework nanopb -framework openssl_grpc -framework protobuf -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework WebKit -framework Pods_MyDogwalk -framework StoreKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyDogwalk.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyDogwalk_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.app/MyDogwalk

**What have I tried?**

- I've reinstalled CocoaPods
- I've reinstalled the GoogleMobileAds pod 100 times.
- I've downloaded the newest GoogleService-info.plist

After I reinstalled the GoogleMobileAds I got everything to work fine. But once I restarted Xcode / the MacBook it was all gone again. And the same error appeared.

Note: If I click on the General tab and scrolls down to Framework, Libraries and Embedded Content and tries to add the GoogleAdMob to it, I cannot find it.

How can I do to fix this error? And why does it appear?

Comment: Apparently this problem might be result of opening the .xcodeproj Xcode project instead of the .xcworkspace Xcode workspace. Try opening the workspace instead and the error should gone away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to delete your DerivedData folder (Xcode will recreate it).

Comment: Where can I find that one?

Comment: From your log, `/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 1):

What version of GoogleMobileAds are you installing? In the [release note](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes), support for iOS 13 starts at 7.50.0.

Also make sure you are using the latest CocoaPods version.

Comment: I am using 7.50.0

I do have the latest CocoaPods version downloaded. (Downloaded it like 20min ago)